# update the table row in javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

```js
     function TutorCourseTableRow(id) {
            debugger;
        var datas = [];
        var Subject = $('#ddlSubject option:selected').text().trim();
        var SubjectId = $('#ddlSubject').val().trim();
        var SchoolLevel = $('#ddlSchoollevel option:selected').text().trim();
        var SchoolLevelId = $('#ddlSchoollevel').val().trim();

            var selectedCourses = '';
            var selectedCourseIDs = '';

            $.each($('#ddlSelectedCourse option'), function (key, value) {
                selectedCourseIDs += $(this).val() + ',';
            });
            $.each($('#ddlSelectedCourse option'), function (key, value) {
                selectedCourses += $(this).text() + ',';
            });
            selectedCourseIDs = selectedCourseIDs.replace(/,\s*$/, "");

            selectedCourses = selectedCourses.replace(/,\s*$/, "");


            $('#tbl_TutorcoursList tbody tr').each(function () {
                debugger;
                 $tblrow = $(this);
                var subject = $tblrow.find("[name=sub]").text();
                var schoolLevel = $tblrow.find("[name=sclevl]").text();
                var subPriorty = $tblrow.find("[name=subjctpriorty]").text();
                var schlPriorty = $tblrow.find("[name=schllvlpriorty]").text();
                var selectedcourses = $tblrow.find("[name=selectdcours]").text();
                var selectedcoursesId = $tblrow.find("[name=selectdcoursId]").text();

                var obj = {};
                obj.Subject = subject;
                obj.SchoolLevel = schoolLevel;
                obj.subjectPriorty = subPriorty;
                obj.SchoolPriorty = schlPriorty;
                obj.selectedcourse = selectedcourses;
                obj.selectedcoursesId = selectedcoursesId;
                datas.push(obj);
            });

            if (datas.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++)
                {
                    debugger;

                    const ArrayA = datas[i].selectedcourse.split(",");
                    const ArrayB = selectedCourses.split(",");

                    const intersection = ArrayA.filter(value => ArrayB.includes(value));
                    const commonCSV = intersection.join(",");


                    if (datas[i].Subject == Subject && datas[i].SchoolLevel == SchoolLevel && commonCSV == "")
                    {
                        var ret = '<tr><td name="sub">' + Subject + '</td><td hidden name="subId">' + SubjectId + '</td><td name="sclevl">' + SchoolLevel + '</td><td hidden name="sclevlId">' + SchoolLevelId + '</td><td name="selectdcours">' + datas[i].selectedcourse +','+ selectedCourses + '</td><td hidden name="selectdcoursId">' +datas[i].selectedcoursesId+','+ selectedCourseIDs + '</td><td name="subjctpriorty">' + subjctpriorty + '</td><td name="schllvlpriorty">' + schllvlpriorty + '</td><td><i title="Click on this button to edit the details" class="fa fa-pencil btnedit fev-cursor" aria-hidden="true" onclick= "TutorCourseEdit(this)"; data-id=' + id + '></i><i title="Click on this button to delete the details" class="fa fa-trash btndelete color-red fev-cursor ml10" aria-hidden="true" onclick= "TutorCourseDelete(this)";" data-id=' + id + '></i></td></td></tr>'

                        // Add changed Tutorcourse to table
                        $($tblrow).after(ret);
                        // Remove original TutorCourse
                        $($tblrow).remove();
                        break;
                    }
                 

                    if (datas[i].Subject == Subject)
                    {
                        subjctpriorty = datas[i].subjectPriorty;
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        var sub = [];
                        datas.filter(function (item) {
                            debugger;
                            if (sub.indexOf(item.Subject) == -1) {
                                sub.push(item.Subject);
                            }
                        });
                        subjctpriorty = sub.length + 1;
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
                    debugger;
                    var result = datas.filter(function (el) {          //If subject and subject priority is same this loop will execute
                                                                         //and schoollevel proiorty will get increment
                        debugger;
                        return el.Subject == Subject;
                    });
                    schllvlpriorty = result.length + 1;
                }
            }



   
        var ret = '<tr><td name="sub">' + Subject + '</td><td hidden name="subId">' + SubjectId + '</td><td name="sclevl">' + SchoolLevel + '</td><td hidden name="sclevlId">' + SchoolLevelId + '</td><td name="selectdcours">' + selectedCourses + '</td><td hidden name="selectdcoursId">' + selectedCourseIDs + '</td><td name="subjctpriorty">' + subjctpriorty + '</td><td name="schllvlpriorty">' + schllvlpriorty + '</td><td><i title="Click on this button to edit the details" class="fa fa-pencil btnedit fev-cursor" aria-hidden="true" onclick= "TutorCourseEdit(this)"; data-id=' + id + '></i><i title="Click on this button to delete the details" class="fa fa-trash btndelete color-red fev-cursor ml10" aria-hidden="true" onclick= "TutorCourseDelete(this)";" data-id=' + id + '></i></td></td></tr>'

        return ret;
    }
```

Hi,i need to update table row if the subject and school level remains same but courses are different but in my code its creating new row rather it should update in the same row(I tried but not able to acheive my functionality)
Could you please help me in this to acheive this functionality?
Above is my code

The scenarios right now working are

If i click on add button

There are 5 things
a)subject
b)school level
c)Courses
d)subject priority
e)School level priroity

a)First if i add subject,school level,courses the subject priority and school level priroty will be 1
For next adding rows below scenarios works
i)If subject is same and school level changes subject priroty will be same and school level priority will get increment
ii)If subject changes and irrespective of school level changes/not the subject priorty will get increment  and school level priroty will start in sequence manner for every individual subject

[This is my UI](https://ibb.co/XStL6yG)